# Multiple LDAP repositories with Spring LDAP Repository

Tags: spring, spring-ldap, spring-repositories

I would like to set more than one LDAP repositories with Spring LDAP. My aim is to create or update objects  in all repositories at the same time.

I use LdapRepository Spring interface and I think that isn't possible for now.

I wonder if I can create my own LdapRepository extending the Spring one but I have no idea how to start.

This my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories("com.xxx.repository.ldap")
@PropertySource("classpath:ldap.properties")
public class LdapConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment ldapProperties;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSourceCustom contextSourceTarget() {
        LdapContextSourceCustom ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSourceCustom();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap.url"));
        ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap.base"));
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap.userDn"));
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap.password"));
        ldapContextSource.setKeyStoreFile(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap.truststore"));

        return ldapContextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(){
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSourceTarget());
    }
}
```

And to be complete, one repository:

```
public interface LdapUserRepository extends LdapRepository<LdapUser> {

}
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** It is possible specify more than one LDAP Repository configuration.  Please see the following example. [**Notice:** This depends on spring-boot libraries]

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories("com.xxx.repository.ldap")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LdapProperties.class)
public class LdapConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="contextSource1")
    public LdapContextSource contextSourceTarget(LdapProperties ldapProperties) {
        LdapContextSource source = new LdapContextSource();
        source.setUserDn(this.properties.getUsername());
        source.setPassword(this.properties.getPassword());
        source.setBase(this.properties.getBase());
        source.setUrls(this.properties.determineUrls(this.environment));
        source.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(Collections.<String,Object>unmodifiableMap(this.properties.getBaseEnvironment()));
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(@Qualifier("contextSource1") LdapContextSource contextSource){
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }
}
```

You can use the `spring.ldap` prefix in `application.properties` to configure the above `LdapConfiguration`.  You can see the available properties by checking out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ldap/LdapProperties.java.

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages="com.yyy.repository.ldap", ldapTemplateRef="ldapTemplate2")
public class LdapConfiguration2 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="ldapProperties2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.ldap2")
    public LdapProperties ldapProperties() {
        return new LdapProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name="contextSource2")
    public LdapContextSource contextSourceTarget(@Qualifier("ldapProperties2") LdapProperties ldapProperties) {
        LdapContextSource source = new LdapContextSource();
        source.setUserDn(this.properties.getUsername());
        source.setPassword(this.properties.getPassword());
        source.setBase(this.properties.getBase());
        source.setUrls(this.properties.determineUrls(this.environment));
        source.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(Collections.<String,Object>unmodifiableMap(this.properties.getBaseEnvironment()));
        return source;
    }

    @Bean(name="ldapTemplate2")
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(@Qualifier("contextSource2") LdapContextSource contextSource){
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }
}
```

`LdapConfiguration2` will be configured by the `spring.ldap2` prefix in `application.properties`.

**2)** I don't think extending the Repository is the solution.  I would recommend creating a `@Service` method that iterated through your repositories and applied the updates.  I will provide two approaches below.

Example 1)

```
@Service
public class UpdateRepositories {
    public void updateAllRepositories(LdapUserRepository userRepository1, LdapUserRepository userRepository2) {
        // apply updates to userRepository1 and userRepository2
    }
}
```

Example 2)

```
@Service
public class UpdateRepositories {
    public void updateAllRepositories(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        Map<String, LdapRepository> ldapRepositories = appContext.getBeansofType(LdapRepository.class)
        // iterate through map and apply updates
    }
}
```

*I haven't compiled this code, so let me know if something is off or if you need additional guidance.*

Comment: In the example 2, I get only one LdapRepository (the first one instantiate I think).

Comment: This example is dependent upon you having more than one implementation of LdapRepository.

Comment: I added answer with complete example with two entities

Comment: Do you have another `@Service` that takes care of Family updates as well?

Comment: yes, I have a service for each LDAP object and as much repositories

Answer (score 3):

I don't known if I understood correctly but here is what we did:

1. Global configuration class

   ```
   @Bean("odm")
   public ObjectDirectoryMapper odm() {
       return new DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper();
   };
   ```
2. First LDAP configuration class

   ```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:ldap-one.properties")
   public class LdapOneConfiguration {

       @Autowired
       Environment ldapProperties;

       @Bean(name = "contextSourceOne")
       public LdapContextSourceCustom contextSourceLdapOneTarget() {
           LdapContextSourceCustom ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSourceCustom();
           ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-one.url"));
           ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-one.base"));
           ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-one.userDn"));
           ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-one.password"));
           ldapContextSource.setKeyStoreFile(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-one.truststore"));

           return ldapContextSource;
       }

       @Bean(name = "ldapTemplateOne")
       public LdapTemplate ldapOneTemplate(@Qualifier("contextSourceOne") LdapContextSourceCustom contextSource) {
           return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
       }

       @Bean(name = "ldapUserRepoOne")
       public LdapUserRepository ldapUserRepositoryOne(@Qualifier("ldapTemplateOne") LdapTemplate ldapTemplate,
           @Qualifier("odm") ObjectDirectoryMapper odm) {
           return new LdapUserRepository(ldapTemplate, odm);
       }

       @Bean(name = "ldapFamilyRepoOne")
       public LdapFamilyRepository ldapFamilyRepositoryOne(@Qualifier("ldapTemplateOne") LdapTemplate ldapTemplate,
           @Qualifier("odm") ObjectDirectoryMapper odm) {
           return new LdapFamilyRepository(ldapTemplate, odm);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Second LDAP configuration class

   ```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:ldap-two.properties")
   public class LdapTwoConfiguration {
       @Autowired
       Environment ldapProperties;

       @Bean(name = "contextSourceTwo")
       public LdapContextSourceCustom contextSourceLdapTwoTarget() {
           LdapContextSourceCustom ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSourceCustom();
           ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-two.url"));
           ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-two.base"));
           ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-two.userDn"));
           ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-two.password"));
           ldapContextSource.setKeyStoreFile(ldapProperties.getProperty("ldap-two.truststore"));

           return ldapContextSource;
       }

       @Bean(name = "ldapTemplateTwo")
       public LdapTemplate ldapTwoTemplate(@Qualifier("contextSourceTwo") LdapContextSourceCustom contextSource) {
           return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
       }

       @Bean(name = "ldapUserRepoTwo")
       public LdapUserRepository ldapUserRepositoryTwo(@Qualifier("ldapTemplateTwo") LdapTemplate ldapTemplate,
           @Qualifier("odm") ObjectDirectoryMapper odm) {
           return new LdapUserRepository(ldapTemplate, odm);
       }

       @Bean(name = "ldapFamilyRepoTwo")
       public LdapFamilyRepository ldapFamilyRepositoryTwo(@Qualifier("ldapTemplateTwo") LdapTemplate ldapTemplate,
           @Qualifier("odm") ObjectDirectoryMapper odm) {
           return new LdapFamilyRepository(ldapTemplate, odm);
       }

   }
   ```
4. LdapUser repository

   ```
   public class LdapUserRepository extends SimpleLdapRepository<LdapUser> {

       public LdapUserRepository(LdapOperations ldapOperations, ObjectDirectoryMapper odm) {
           super(ldapOperations, odm, LdapUser.class);
       }
   }
   ```
5. LdapFamily repository

   ```
   public class LdapFamilyRepository extends SimpleLdapRepository<LdapFamily> {

       public LdapFamilyRepository(LdapOperations ldapOperations, ObjectDirectoryMapper odm) {
           super(ldapOperations, odm, LdapFamily.class);
       }
   }
   ```
6. LdapUser service (same for LdapFamily service)

   ```
   @Service
   public class LdapUserServiceImpl implements LdapUserService {

       @Autowired
       private ApplicationContext appContext;

       private LdapUserRepository uniqueLdapUserRepo;

       private List<LdapUserRepository> ldapUserRepoList;

       @PostConstruct
       private void setUniqueRepo() {
           uniqueLdapUserRepo = appContext.getBeansOfType(LdapUserRepository.class).values().iterator().next();
           ldapUserRepoList = new ArrayList<>(appContext.getBeansOfType(LdapUserRepository.class).values());
       }

       @Override
       public LdapUser getUser(String uid) {
           return uniqueLdapUserRepo.findOne(query().where("uid").is(uid));
       }

       @Override
       public void saveUser(LdapUser user) {
           for(LdapUserRepository repo: ldapUserRepoList){
               repo.save(user);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

We deleted the auto configuration of LDAP repo:

```
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "com.afklm.paul.repository.ldap", ldapTemplateRef = "ldapTwoTemplate")
```

Thanks ryan2049 for your help.

Answer (score 1):

there is actually an easier way now:

create multiple configuration that is anotated with **@EnableLdapRepositories** with corresponding attributes

**Create first configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "first.ldap.package.repository.**", ldapTemplateRef = "firstLdapTemplate")
public class FirstLDAPConfig {
   ....detail


    @Bean("firstLdapTemplate")
    public LdapTemplate firstLdapTemplate() {
        ...template creation
    }

}
```

**Create second configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "second.ldap.package.repository.**", ldapTemplateRef = "secondLdapTemplate")
public class SecondLDAPConfig {
   ....detail

    @Bean("secondLdapTemplate")
    public LdapTemplate secondLdapTemplate() {
        ...template creation
    }
}
```

each configuration should handle it's own contextSource
then only the specified repository within the EnableLdapRepositories annotation will use that specific ContextSource and LdapTemplate